# FancyBox thumbnail for video

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'd like to use FancyBox for video, but have my page show a thumbnail without having to explicitly create one.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/fancybox.html

This page presents two thumbnails that present the same video.  If you click on the first, FancyBox pops up the video, which is my intended result.  However, I have to generate a thumbnail.  The second uses the HTML5 video tag, which abstracts a thumbnail to present from the video without me having to explicitly create it.

Is there a way I can achieve both - identify to FancyBox as a video for popup, but still present a thumbnail from the video object without explicitly creating one?

Answer (score 0):

fancybox already generates thumbnail image from your video, but, since you only have one video in the gallery, thumbnail list is not generated. Because, well, there is no need for that, you just can not navigate to next/previous video.

So, add more videos to your gallery and thumbnails should appear.

Comment: My apologies; I could have been more clear.  I meant a phpBB thumbnail, not a FancyBox thumbnail.  Here's a page from my production site, with multiple videos - all presented with the video tag and a width constraint to render them as thumbnails:  http://59plymouth.net/59forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=3344&start=12

Comment: They are already stored within the forum, without thumbnails.  In my previous example, the FancyBox presentation requires an "img src=" thumbnail - but I have none, except for the one I created for the comparison.

Comment: Ohmigosh, @Janis!  This works!  Is it street-legal HTML5?!?  <a data-fancybox="gallery1" data-type="video" href="../59test/download/file.php?id=16191"><video width="350" height="auto" controls=""><source src="../59test/download/file.php?id=16191"></video></a>

Comment: OK - I've implemented these changes in my test phpBB board, and the FancyBox gallery works great!  However, while I wouldn't expect a FancyBox thumbnail for the .mp3 (that I'm calling a video to get added to the gallery), I'm not getting thumbs for the two .mp4's either.  I thought you suggested I would get those, if I had more than one...  Here's the link:  http://59plymouth.net/59test/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3353&p=22872#p22872

Comment: Sorry, I'm curious, but what thumbnail did you expected from mp3 file? You have to add thumbnail by yourself where thumbnail can not be retrieved automatically, simply add `data-thumb` attribute (for example, `data-thumb="https://source.unsplash.com/Hau6K6VP5vs/240x160"`)

Comment: sorry for my tortured English.  I *wouldn't* expect a FancyBox thumbnail for the mp3.  Thanks for the tip about the data-thumb attribute, I've added it for the mp3.  I'm still not getting thumbs for the mp4's, though.  You said "fancybox already generates thumbnail image from your video, but, since you only have one video in the gallery, thumbnail list is not generated...add more videos to your gallery and thumbnails should appear."  But I'm not seeing them.

Comment: I can swear that you originally had image instead of the video as the preview. Because then it would be used as thumbnail image, see https://jsfiddle.net/c5mtwg07/

Comment: You are correct - as I describe in my "Ohmigosh!" comment above, using the video tag as the preview permits me to display a phpBB thumbnail of the video. In uploading mp4's, I haven't generated phpBB thumbs for my videos, but this approach permits me to display one without the same, default image for all mp4's.  Does this defeat the FancyBox thumb generation, then?

Comment: I could use the data-thumb attribute for a default mp4 thumb, just as I am using it for mp3's.  But discriminating between mp4 thumbs would then not be possible (as it is in the phpBB gallery).

Comment: Look, if you provide a thumbnail image, then fancybox will use it. If not, then ... it will not. If you expect that the script will download video, extract some frame and use that to generate thumbnail image (like the browser does), then you expecting too much. I am sorry, but I do not understand what other answer you are looking for.

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your first statement in this thread:  "fancybox already generates thumbnail image from your video".  And yes, I did think that because HTML5 does generate a thumbnail from the video, fancybox might do so too.  But I take your point that I am expecting too much!  It is already amaaaaaaazing what I am able to do with such a little bit of code.  Thank you so very much!